# Loading font-family into the web application will display the default one for the first 2 seconds

Tags: css, angular, asp.net-core, font-family

I'm trying to load the Ubuntu-Bold font-family to my web application (ASP.NET CORE API + Angular). The Ubuntu-Bold.ttf file is located on assets/fonts folder and I also added `@font-face { font-family: 'Ubuntu-Bold'; src: url(assets/fonts/Ubuntu-Bold.ttf); } body { margin: 0; font-family: 'Ubuntu-Bold'; }` in to the styles.scss file. The font-family its applied to my application but after 2 seconds after the application started running.

Default font-family appears first at the beginning of application:
[image]

After 2 second the desired font-family its applied: [image]

As you can see there its a big difference between this two fonts so I'm trying to find a solution in order to apply my font `Ubuntu-Bold` before the application its displayed in order to not see that change of family fonts after 2 seconds after application started.

Comment: Is your stylesheet loaded after javascript in the HTML? Is your server responding quickly? Did you try to [preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload) the font file in the `head` tag? If the font is on another domain, did you try to [preconnect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preconnect) to that domain?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `preload` on your link tag, it tells the browser to load this stylesheet before the main part of your web app.

it should look something like that:

```
<link rel="preload" href="your/path/xxx.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>
```

or if you want your entire styles to load first

```
  <link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">
```

you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload)

Comment: I tried adding ` <link rel="preload" href="styles.scss" as="style">` in to the index.html but i got an 404 error.

Comment: Did you use the same path you used to load your styles.css without the preload tag? What happens when you type the same path in your browser?